# What $this->bootstrap('view') will do?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new to zend framework. I found code in bootstrap file as below.

```
 protected function _initDoctype()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('view');
        $view = $this->getResource('view');
        $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
    }
```

can anyone explain me what "**$this->bootstrap('view');**" this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward, it literally **bootstraps** the View object.
Bootstraping is a step where you set up (configure and instantiate) your object, resolve dependencies, etc.
It is done because the View Object *must* be set before to be able to set a Doctype.

Answer (score 4):

From the [same page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-layout.html) where your snippet comes:

> Now that we have a view, let's flesh
>   out our _initDoctype() method. In it,
>   we will first ensure the View resource
>   has run, fetch the view object, and
>   then configure it.

Answer (score 3):

It sets up the view resource so that you can access it. Without it the following line would not return anything to put in the $view variable and you'd get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function doctype() on a non-object.
```